extra line describing amsmath versions at the start of the generated pdf file
I am using the Texifier software to write simple latex files. I noticed an extra line appears at the start of the generated pdf file. Refer to the screenshots, this line describes several versions of "amsmath.sty". I don't know how to get rid of it. It looks like there are errors in these files itself. For your information, the tex version control manager I am using is MikTex.
The latex code
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{comment}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}

\begin{document}
\section*{Q1}
\subsection*{(a)}
\end{document}


The generated pdf file

The issues


Welcome to TeX SE. Could you copy the code that produce this error? It'll be easier to see what is going on.

You're probably trying a newer version of amsmath.sty on an older LaTeX distribution. Likely TeX Live 2017 or earlier.

You are trying to use a recent version of amsmath.sty on an older TeX distribution.
If I try the last version of amsmath with TeX Live 2017, I get
! Undefined control sequence.
l.26 \DeclareRelease
                    {}{1994-06-01}{amsmath-2018-12-01.sty}
?

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.26 \DeclareRelease{}{1
                        994-06-01}{amsmath-2018-12-01.sty}
?
! Undefined control sequence.
l.27 \DeclareRelease
                    {}{2018-12-01}{amsmath-2018-12-01.sty}
?
! Undefined control sequence.
l.28 \DeclareCurrentRelease
                           {}{2019-04-01}
?

which matches the errors you're getting.
Update your TeX distribution. If you can't, don't try to use newer versions of packages.

do I just update all packages in the MiKTeX console? It does not solve the problem. Or do i have to re-install the MikTex application?

@FellowInstituteOfMathophile Likely you did updates only in User mode and not also in Admin mode. Try a full reinstall.
